# Angular.. how to hide the button based on cognito groups

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, angular8, serverless

All,We are using cognito for our serverless application, as part of one new functionality, we are using cognito groups for roles based permission. So if the issue is part of a group .. he will have permission to add some data if not the add button is not visible.

But could not get the required output by doing below can someone help me?

Here is some sample code

event.component.html
'''

```
<a *ngIf="!_auth.Isgroupin()" routerLink="/cards">Login</a>


<a *ngIf="!_auth.IsLoggedIn()" routerLink="/map">seee</a>
```

'''

....
Service

'''

```
signIn(email, password) { 

    const authenticationData = {
      Username : email,
      Password : password,
    };
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    const userData = {
      Username : email,
      Pool : userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
          console.log(result)

          var sessionIdInfo = (result.getIdToken().decodePayload());
          console.log(sessionIdInfo['cognito:groups'])
          console.log('session token: ' + result.getIdToken().getExpiration())
          observer.next(sessionIdInfo['cognito:groups']);
          observer.next(result);
          observer.complete();
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          observer.error(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
 Isgroupin():boolean{
  var group=( this.getAuthenticatedUser().getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().decodePayload()['cognito:groups']);

  return (group['cognito:groups']) != null;


 }
  IsLoggedIn() {    
    return userPool.getCurrentUser() != null;
  }
```

'''

Comment: IsLoggedIn and  _auth.Isgroupin() should return true or false...just console those two and watch the console..

Comment: @shafeeq.. yes that is what I was trying but could not achieve it can you please see the code and help me fix it

Comment: please add the console that you are getting after this code..